# IOS local notification custom 30 seconds sound got cut off when on screen banner went up(app in foreground) I am using voip push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

Does anyone know is it possible to keep playing the custom notification sound after notification banner went up (app in foreground, in background it works perfectly full 30 seconds).